# Eclipse is generating a constructor that already exists

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm making a game using the libgdx library. I have a class called `World` and a class called `WorldTile`.

In the `World` class I create a new `WorldTile` and Eclipse tells me the constructor is undefined, but it is. If I take the "possible corrective action" to create such constructor, it cause an error in `WorldTile` that there are duplicate methods.

Code in `World.java`:

```
worldTile = new WorldTile(renderZone, TileImages.FLOOR_PLANK_YELLOW, TileImages.WALL_BRICK_GREEN, true);
```

Code in `WorldTile.java`:

```
public WorldTile(Position renderZone, int floorType, int wallType, boolean isHidden) 
{
    this.position = renderZone;
    this.isHidden = true;
}

public WorldTile(Position renderZone, int floorPlankYellow, 
                  int wallBrickGreen, boolean b) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

The second constructor is the auto-generated constructed by Eclipse, to show that I in fact had the right constructor written, but Eclipse claimed it wasn't there.

As per a suggestion in comments, I restarted Eclipse, and that worked. Have you tried turning it off and on again? Thanks for all of the suggestions.

Comment: You are passing `renderZone` into the parameters, but didn't show or tell us what type it is. Same with the other variables being passed in. Show us the types of the values you are passing in

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug. Please add World and WorldTile including their imports. Thx

Comment: Is it possible you wrote several class named `WorldTile` ?

Comment: Just a sidenote. You pass in the parameter `isHidden`, but you always set the field `isHidden` to true, no matter what the parameter was.

Comment: They have the same signature

Comment: I definitely have only one class named WorldTile.

Comment: renderZone is a Position object, as the constructors above imply.

Comment: isHidden is a variable to determine if the room is accessible by the player outright. If isHidden isn't set by a constructor, it defaults to false

Comment: I'm not showing the default constructor above, which sets isHidden to false

Answer (score 0):

Since both constructors have the same parameter types, the compiler doesn't know which constructor to use. Different constructors for the same object must have a different set of parameters. Also, if you're passing in a piece of data to construct the object, generally you want to actually do something with that data...

EDIT: For a quick fix, simply delete the second constructor.

EDIT2: Since I seem to have misread your post originally...My advice is to make sure you are passing the appropriate types to the constructor.

Comment: I think the second constructor is actually the one generated by Eclipse after "corrective action" have been clicked.

Comment: Ah, I see that now...I wasn't sure.

Comment: Since the second one is generated by Eclipse, I can only surmise that it is impossible that I would be using the wrong data types

Answer (score 0):

to have two Constructors for a class the parameter types must differ. having the two constructors

```
public MyClass(int a, int b) { // your code } along with

public MyClass(int c, int d) { // your code }
```

wont work. since both constructors would take two integers. So Java won't know which one to choose. you can have various constructors for a class given that their signature (combination of methodName and parameterList) differs.

so

```
MyClass(int a, int b) { // your code } along with 
MyClass(int a, int b, int c)  { // your code }
```

is totally fine. see why?

also as mmitaru suggested, you usually want to create i.e. instantiate an object and have a reference to it so that you can use/manipulate it.

```
myObjType obj1; // declaration : obj1 should hold, so to say reference to objects of type myObjType 

new myObjType(...) // actually creates such an object (where ... are the parameters the constructors expects) 

myObjType obj1 = new myObjType(...) // declaration and initialization in a single step

obj1.aMethod() // calls the method aMethod on the object of type myObjType
```